# Extracting links from pdfs in R with a regex

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I am trying to clean a list of pdfs of links. I want to include this in my cleaning function and therefore use regexes. And yes, I spend more time than I like to admit googling and browsing though questions here.
My pdfs are split into lines, so it is not one consecutive string.
I have a piece of code that gives me only one link as result (even though there should be many). 
All other options I tried included a lot of text I want to keep in my dataset.

I have tried multiple options outside my function but they will not run on texts, only on examples.

I want to catch everything from the www to the first white space after all the things that come after the .org or .html or whatever (e.g. /questions/ask/somethingelse

I tried simulating some things

```
w <- "www.smthing.org/knowledge/school/principal.\r"
z <- "www.oecd.de\r"
x <- "www.bla.pdfwerr\r .irgendwas" # should not catch that, too many characters after the . 
m <-  "           www.cognitioninstitute.org/index.php/Publications/ 
 bla test smth 
  .gtw, www.stmthing-else.html.\r"
n <- "decoy"


l <- list(w,z,x,m,n)

regmatches(l, regexpr("w{3}\\.[a-z]*\\.[a-z]{2,4}.*?[[:space:]]", l))
```

My current working state also only catches the first occurence in that particular line, instead stopping at the space (line m in my example) and then including the next link as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I get no results at all with that.

Comment: `regexpr("w{3}\\.\\S*",  l)`

Comment: @Lieven Base R `regexpr` uses either PCRE or TRE. In this case, OP uses TRE.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - you mistake me for someone who knows what he's talking about, I had to look up TRE :). Your regex is way simpler but it matches the trailing `\r`.

Comment: @Lieven `\S` does not match whitespace and `\r` is a CR char.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thanks, I interpreted that as actual being part of the string. It still matches the trailing `.` in `www.smthing.org/knowledge/school/principal.` though *(unless R also treats that as a control character)*

Comment: Yes, a dot is not whitespace. `regexpr("w{3}\\.\\S*\\b", l)` would work if that final punctuation is not to be matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - You should post that as an answer.

Comment: If that works for @H.Stevens I will.

Comment: Hahaa! It works!! I found the problem! And it was none of your work but my mistake (using gregexpr instread of regexpr did it). And of course your help! Thank you @WiktorStribiżew and everyone else!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
regmatches(l, gregexpr("w{3}\\.\\S*\\b", l))
```

The `gregexpr` function will let you extract all occurrences of the pattern.

Note that most users prefer spelling out `www` instead of using `w{3}`.

**Pattern details**

- `w{3}` - three `w` chars
- `\\.` - a dot
- `\\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `\\b` - word boundary.